# how to use parallel_for over a recursive_directory_iterator?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, concurrency

I can't work out how to use the Concurrency::parallel_for over a recursive_directory_iterator, the compiler doesn't like the Step param.

Can you use the parallel_for[each] stuff with anything other than arrays?

simple code:

```
    recursive_directory_iterator dir(cwd, directory_options::skip_permission_denied);
    recursive_directory_iterator end_dir;

    parallel_for(begin(dir), end(dir), begin(dir), [&](recursive_directory_iterator dir) {

    });
```

results in a cahjillion errors about the third param _Step:

```
Error   C2678   binary '<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    app c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\ppl.h  2501    
Error   C2678   binary '>=': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   app c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\ppl.h  2507    
Error   C2784   'unknown-type std::operator -(const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::move_iterator<_RanIt2> &)': could not deduce template argument for 'const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator'    app c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\ppl.h  2514    
Error   C2784   'unknown-type std::operator -(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)': could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator'   app c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\ppl.h  2514    
Error   C2676   binary '-': 'std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator   app c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\ppl.h  2514    
Error   C2672   '_Parallel_for_partitioned_impl': no matching overloaded function found app c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\ppl.h  2525    
Error   C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'void Concurrency::_Parallel_for_partitioned_impl(_Index_type,_Diff_type,_Diff_type,const _Function &,const Concurrency::auto_partitioner &)'    app c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\ppl.h  2525
```

It looks like I need to adapt the iterator somehow but I'm not sure how - I could convert the dir recurse to an array but that doesn't feel quite right.

Any ideas?

TIA

Comment: thats not the same question at all!

Comment: The `recursive_directory_iterator` is an [InputIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator), so doesn't have the operators `<`, `>=`, or `-`. Probably makes in unsuitable for parallel work.

Comment: According to documentation `parallel_for` does not work with iterators. Only `parallel_for_each` does. And, according to documentation, it works only with _random-access_ and _forward_ iterators, which `recursive_directory_iterator` is not.

Comment: Thanks guys, that's all I wanted to know - can't mark those as answers though.